# $C^\infty(M)$-linear maps are local

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, vector-bundles

Very often in mathematical physics literature I've heard a fact that probably (if I've understood it correctly) translates as follows.

> Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold, and denote by $C^\infty(M)$ the
>   ring of smooth real functions $M\to\Bbb{R}$. Let now $E$ and $F$ be
>   vector bundles on $M$, and notice that the spaces of smooth sections
>   $\Gamma(E)$ and $\Gamma(F)$ are modules over $C^\infty(M)$.  Let now
>   $f:\Gamma(E)\to\Gamma(F)$ be a smooth, $\Bbb{R}$-linear function. The following are
>   equivalent.
>
> - $f$ is $C^\infty(M)$-linear;
> - $f$ is "local", meaning that given sections $\phi,\psi$ which agree at the point $p\in M$,
>     then $f(\phi)$ and $f(\psi)$ agree at $p$ too.

First of all, is the above correct? If not, what is the correct statement? Also, where can I find a reference and a proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\{e_i\}$ be a local frame defined in an open set $U\subset M$ over $\Gamma(E)$ and $\{f_j\}$ be the local frame over $\Gamma(F)$ generated by the image of the $e_i$'s under the action of $f$. That is,

$$f_i = f(e_i).$$

Then, any sections $\phi,\psi\in \Gamma(E)$ can be expressed locally in terms of the frame $\{e_i\}$,

$$\phi = \phi^i e_i,$$
$$\psi = \psi^i e_i,$$

where $\phi^i$ and $\psi^i$ are scalar functions on $M$. The two sections $\phi$ and $\psi$ are the same on $U$ if and only if $\psi^i = \phi^i$. We can then we can use $C^\infty(M)$ linearity to show that:

$$f(\phi) = \phi^i f(e_i) = \phi^i f_i,$$
$$f(\psi) = \psi^i f(e_i) = \psi^i f_i.$$

Again, we have that the sections $f(\phi)$ and $f(\psi)$ are the same on $U$ if and only if $\psi^i = \phi^i$.

This means that $\phi = \psi \Leftrightarrow f(\phi) = f(\psi)$ on $U$. Of course the result is valid for every point $p\in U$, so that your conclusion follows.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this assumes that $\phi$ and $\psi$ agree on the whole neighborhood $U$ of $p$, not just at $p$, right?

Comment: You can reduce it to a point by instead of using a frame simply choosing a basis of the fiber at a given point $p$. Let $E_p$ be such fiber and consider the $\{e_i\}$ to be a basis for $E_p$. Define again $f_i = f(e_i)$ so that in the point $p$ we have 
$$\phi(p) = \phi^ie_i,$$
$$\psi(p) = \psi^ie_i,$$
where now $\phi^i$ and $\psi^i$ are real numbers.Then $C^\infty(M)$ linearity implies linearity over real numbers on every point and the same argument follows.